# Need to remove duplicate nodes in linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am attempting to write code that will remove the duplicate nodes in a singly-linked list.
 The duplicates removed are only removed until the number stored in the next node changes. 

For example, if the input list is `[ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ]`,
 the output list is `[ 0 1 0 3 1 0 ]`.
I have attempted to write the code and tried multiple things. Each time when I call the function it either returns the original linked list or just the original head and original tail. 
I attempted creating a temporary linked list and storing values in that list but it does not return properly. 
My latest attempt is in the code snippet below and only returns the head and tail of the original list.

My question is, how I should proceed with this code? I tried to draw it out and visualize it but it did not help. 
I am not looking for code to be written just a push in the correct direction.
I think that the code I have now is a dead end and I may have to restart from scratch. 
What is the best way to start to implement this code to achieve an answer?

```
public void squish() {

    SListNode current = head;
    SListNode iterator = current.next;

    while (iterator != null){
        if (current.equals(iterator)){
            iterator = iterator.next;
        } else {
            if (current.next.equals (null)) {
                break;
            } else {
                head.next = iterator;
                current = iterator;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Egor -- It's probably homework....

Comment: A set would remove all duplicates. Not just the consecutive ones. And the OP seems to need to implement his own list for homework.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you might want to read the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), or check out [the formatting reference provided while asking questions](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi) - it's very hard to read your question. You'll want to format the code snippets as code snippets.

Comment: ... you'll also want to add some context to your question. What is your problem exactly? As it stands your question is likely to be downvoted and [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) because it's difficult to understand what you need and what you've tried.

Comment: A few hints: `iterator = iterator.next;` is not the same as `current.next = iterator.next;`. You also need to increment your iterator in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

In your current solution you are trying to do 2 things at once, skipping `n` equal numbers and re-arranging your list. This makes the solution a bit more complex than necessary.

What you can do is looping while you have a current node and that current node is followed by another.

now within the loop you have 2 possibilities;

- either the values of current and next are equal, in that case make the node following current (next) the same as the one following the current next.
- or the values are unequal, in that case walk the list by setting the current node to its follower node.

That's it, no explicit assignments to the head reference should be necessary.

Comment: I attempted to change that but the list that is inputed into the function still does not change. When I read through what I wrote now it seems as if I don't actually remove any of the nodes.<br/> I start the while loop the same but then change next to next.next if current == next.<br/> then if that is not true I set current = next. To me it seems as if this won't actually change the list I am trying to squish.

Comment: @Hunter, I think the comparison might be the problem `current == next` will never be `true` unless both pint to the same object. What you probably want is the comparison `current.value == next.value`, assuming value is an integer type and not a String. (also  note that `current.next.equals(null)` calls the method `equals()` on the object referenced by `current.next` to check your next pointer, use `current.next == null`)

Comment: Yea I finally figured that out, that was the issue I had the first time I attempted to solve the problem. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is homework, so I don't want to give a complete solution.

Working directly with iterators is always tricky.  Instead of working in place with a single List, you should consider creating a new List with the solution you want.  e.g., schematically...

```
 Create a new empty List for the result
 Initialize prevValue
 Loop over the values in input list
 If the value is not equal to the prevValue
   add it to the result list
   update prev value
```

Of course, if the class/assignment really wants you to use iterators, ignore the above...

Comment: I don't have to use iterators so I'm going to try this idea. I attempted this at first but I was having issues making sure that the new list was being returned into the main function where I was testing. Thanks you for the code schematics hopefully I can figure it out this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void RemoveDuplicates()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        Node cur = head;

        myDict.Add(head.Data, 1);
        while (cur.Next != null)
        {
            if (myDict.ContainsKey(cur.Next.Data))
                cur.Next = cur.Next.Next;
            else
            {
                myDict.Add(cur.Next.Data, 1);
                cur = cur.Next;
            }


        }
    }
```